# Installed Ubuntu (14.04) on external HDD and lost data

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, data-recovery

I've installed Ubuntu on external HDD without formating and lost 800GB from it. I've installed it from flash drive from Ubuntu to try. When I plug it into turned on win PC, nothing shows, and when I plug it into turned on PC with Ubuntu, just system data are on the HDD, but installation was quick, nothing formated, so I think, my data are there, but somehow hidden. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure nothing was formatted? If windows shows you nothing, that means the HDD most probably was formatted in `ext4`. During installation unfortunately you didn't pay attention at the step of installation location. By default Ubuntu's first option is `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`

Comment: oh.. really "smart".. 2 ways at installation how to delete everything. It was bad choice this OS.. Thankies